# Отключение кеширования css

Tags: html, css, веб-сервер

Такая проблема, меняю файл стилей на сервере, но все браузеры, кроме вкладки инкогнито или частной вкладки, подтягивают старые стили хедера. Я их поменял уже капитально и соответственно выглядит это уродливо, клиенты заходя повторно на сайт видят это.

Как заставить каждый раз скачивать ксс браузер пользователя или отключить кеширование?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, добавил в functions.php время последнего изменения файла.

```
$style = get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css'; 
$lastedit = filemtime($style); 

wp_enqueue_style('theme-style', $style, array(), $lastedit);
```